# AddDbContext() service type activation mode

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

When you create a new Web Application using ASP.NET core RC2 it contains the following code in Startup.cs file -

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

My question is - what is the activation mode of this DbContext object getting injected? Is it transient or scoped or something else?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

`AddDbContext<TContext>` extension method is defined in [EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.cs](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/9186d0b78a3176587eeb0f557c331f635760fe92/src/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore/EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L140) file in [EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework) and contains the following:

```
serviceCollection.TryAddSingleton(p => DbContextOptionsFactory<TContext>(p, optionsAction));
serviceCollection.AddSingleton<DbContextOptions>(p => p.GetRequiredService<DbContextOptions<TContext>>());

serviceCollection.TryAdd(new ServiceDescriptor(typeof(TContext), typeof(TContext), contextLifetime));
```

where contextLifetime is `ServiceLifetime.Scoped` by default, but can be changed.

And keep in mind, that in general, you always can find and analyze ASP.NET Core sources on [github](https://github.com/aspnet)